# Is anyone else having tons of issues when trying to add Admobs to their IOS project?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

One of the many issues is when I try to add the func to show a Rewarded add:

```
func show() {
  if let ad = rewardedAd {
    ad.present(fromRootViewController: self) {
      let reward = ad.adReward
      print("Reward received with currency \(reward.amount), amount \(reward.amount.doubleValue)")
      // TODO: Reward the user.
    }
  } else {
    print("Ad wasn't ready")
  }
}
```

This line throws an error: ad.present(fromRootViewController: self) {
"Cannot convert value of type 'ContentView' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Another issue is the Google Utilities with the install Mobile ads SDK, a lot of items have been deprecated in IOS 12

Example: 'subscriberCellularProvider' is deprecated: first deprecated in IOS 12.0

Has anyone successfully added admobs to an IOS app? If you have any help would be nice, cause the documentation seems outdated.

The Mobile Ads SDK (iOS) for Google AdMob tutorial

Comment: It would seem that `self` must be a `UIViewController` but `self` is a `ContentView`. It seems you must present an ad from a view controller (which makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

Admobs will ** NOT ** work outside of a view controller.  Period.  Full stop.  I use Admob all the time and you must use it from within a view controller.  It will not work any other way.

Try this:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class AdViewController: UIViewController, GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
    
    private var rewardedInterstitialAd: GADRewardedInterstitialAd?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        GADRewardedInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6978759866",
                                       request: GADRequest()) { ad, error in
            if let error = error {
                return print("Failed to load rewarded interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            self.rewardedInterstitialAd = ad
            self.rewardedInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        }
        
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that the ad failed to present full screen content.
    func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
        print("Ad did fail to present full screen content.")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that the ad will present full screen content.
    func adWillPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("Ad will present full screen content.")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that the ad dismissed full screen content.
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("Ad did dismiss full screen content.")
    }
    
    func show() {
        guard let rewardedInterstitialAd = rewardedInterstitialAd else {
            return print("Ad wasn't ready.")
        }
        
        rewardedInterstitialAd.present(fromRootViewController: self) {
            let reward = rewardedInterstitialAd.adReward
            // TODO: Reward the user!
        }
    }
 
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent() {
        GADRewardedInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6978759866",
                                       request: GADRequest()) { ad, error in
            if let error = error {
                return print("Failed to load rewarded interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            self.rewardedInterstitialAd = ad
            self.rewardedInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of implementing a Rewarded Ad through AdMobs?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-interstitial is exactly what you need.  I use the exact same code everytime.

Comment: See my answer above

Comment: Yeah, I am currently using this from the documentation, I was more asking on implementing it into a view. Example, on a button click in content view, bring up the ad.

Comment: You can’t.  It will only work via a view controller.  On the show method it makes it clear that it has to come from a root view controller meaning a specific controller.  Content view, collection view etc won’t work.

Comment: All I want to do is to have a button and have the ad appear, is there a way to do this via the controller?

Comment: Tim, you can add a button to a view controller and within the button action fire the ad.  You cannot do it from a content view.